# How can I extend Backbone.Events in a Typescript ES6 Class?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, backbone.js, typescript

I'm trying to attach Backbone's Events properties onto a TypeScript class, however when I do this...

```
class Foo {
    constructor () {
        _.assign(this, Backbone.Events); // or _.extend()
        this.stopListening(this.otherInstance);
    }
}

let bar = new Foo();
bar.on("myevent", handler);
```

...I get these **compile time** errors:

- `Error TS2339: Property 'stopListening' does not exist on type 'Foo'.`
- `Error TS2339: Property 'on' does not exist on type 'Foo'.`

I'm not very familiar with how TypeScript would approach this, but seems like something it could handle.

Note: looking for a solution that's easy to apply to multiple classes that also need `Backbone.Events` functionality (ie. I don't want to copy/paste all the `on,off,listenTo...` methods, or some funky proxy approach, to every class that needs them).

Since Backbone.Events is just an object, I can't extend it using normal ES6 syntax. Ex)

```
class Foo extends Backbone.Events {}
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of `_.assign` if you use `_.extend` it will work,

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xxVAjoHxg2G7ZeOPiOg2?p=info)

```
    class Foo {
      constructor () {
         _.extend(this, Backbone.Events);
      }
    }

    let bar : any = new Foo();

    bar.on("alert", function(msg) {
      alert("Triggered " + msg);
    });

    bar.trigger("alert", "an event");
```

updated code so that it does not gives compile time error.

**UPDATE**

you may create a class which has all the functions defined for `Backbone.Events` and constructor of it can extend Backbone.Events, which will override all the methods which is just defined for intellisense and type check.

updated the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xxVAjoHxg2G7ZeOPiOg2?p=preview)

```
 class CustomEvents {
    constructor() {
      _.extend(this, Backbone.Events);
    }

    on(eventName: string, callback?: Function, context?: any): any { return; };
    off(eventName?: string, callback?: Function, context?: any): any { return; };
    trigger(eventName: string, ...args: any[]): any { return; };
    bind(eventName: string, callback: Function, context?: any): any { return; };
    unbind(eventName?: string, callback?: Function, context?: any): any { return; };

    once(events: string, callback: Function, context?: any): any { return; };
    listenTo(object: any, events: string, callback: Function): any { return; };
    listenToOnce(object: any, events: string, callback: Function): any { return; };
    stopListening(object?: any, events?: string, callback?: Function): any { return; };
  }
```

and you can extend any class with CustomEvents class like below,

```
  class Foo extends CustomEvents {
    constructor(){
      super(); 
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: The error I'm getting is a TypeScript compile error and not a runtime one. ie. even if I did use `_.extend` I would still have the issue.

Comment: Do you just care about compiling it or you are also looking for intellisense support? If you just want to get rid of compile error you may cast bar to `any` and will compile fine like let bar : any = new Foo();, and will work also at runtime.

Comment: I care about both compiling and intellisense. Casting to `any` will only work for code that's dealing with instances of `Foo`. But the moment I want to go `this.on()` or `this.listenTo()` etc inside the Foo class, I will still get compilation issues. I'll update the question to emphasize this.

Comment: Well, I guess I can still do `(<any>this).on()`, but that still seems like more of a workaround than an elegant way to preserve intellisense/type checking.

Comment: @Trevor :  updated solution so that you may get intellisense and type check as well...  The only thing needs to be taken care is if backbone adds some extra method you have to include in customEvents class as well. Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

On `Backbone.Events` the event handling are attached on the object itself rather than on its `.prototype`, here is how you can correct that:

```
import {Events} from 'backbone';

interface IEventEmitter extends Events {
    emit(event: string, ...args: any[]);
}

function _EventEmitter() {}
_EventEmitter.prototype = Events;
_EventEmitter.prototype.emit = (Events as any).trigger;
export const EventEmitter: new() => IEventEmitter
    = _EventEmitter as any as new() => IEventEmitter;
```

Now use it as by inheritance:

```
class Dog extends EventEmitter {

}

var dog = new Dog;
dog.on('bark', () => console.log('Dog just barked'));
dog.emit('bark');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use typings from here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/backbone
2. Write implementation of Backbone.EventsMixin somewhere right after Backbone script is included:

```js
Backbone.EventsMixin = function () {
    _.assign(this, Backbone.Events);
}
```

3. Then it can be used like this:

```js
class SomeClass extends Backbone.EventsMixin
```